# Código não funcionando

Tags: c

Estou tentando resolver um problema do site UriOnlineJudge ([link do problema](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1112)) e estou recebendo um erro do tipo *Time limit exceeded*, e não estou conseguindo identificar o problema. Posso imaginar que esteja no primeiro scanf(), onde talvez seja necessário ler a entrada sem o uso da tecla ENTER. Segue abaixo o código.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    int X, Y, P, Q;
    int i, j, k, l;
    char carac;
    while(1){
        scanf("%d %d %d", &X, &Y, &P);
        if(X==0 && Y==0 && P==0){
            return 0;
        }
        int campo[X][Y];
        for(i=0;i<X;i++){
            for(j=0;j<Y;j++){
                campo[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
        scanf("%d", &Q);
        int N=0, Z, W, qtd;
        for(i=0;i<Q;i++){
            qtd=0;
            scanf(" %c", &carac);
            if(carac=='A'){
                scanf("%d %d %d", &N, &X, &Y);
                campo[X][Y]+=N;
            }
            else{
                scanf("%d %d %d %d", &X, &Y, &Z, &W);
                for(j=X;j<=Z;j++){
                    if(Y>W){
                        l=Y;
                        Y=W;
                        W=l;
                    }
                    for(k=Y;k<=W;k++){
                        qtd+=campo[j][k];
                    }
                }
                printf("%d\n", qtd*P);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O tempo de execução do seu código está excedendo o limite determinado do problema.

O seu código está demandando muito tempo de execução por causa dos loops internos, o ideal era evitar usar loops internos.

Você pode tentar usar `struct` pra tentar diminuir o tempo de execução do código.

Por exemplo:

Implementar cada mensagem como um ponto

```
struct ponto {
  int x;
  int y;
  int n; //o numero de schweisen
};
```

e guardar cada ponto numa Lista encadeada.